# Extract and list every occurrence of string between two delimiters match from text body

Tags: bash

I would like to understand how to extract all links (starting with `www` and ending with `.com`) from a text body such as below. Multiple occurrences may or may not occur per line.

```
cat body.txt
text more-text url="http://www.link1.com">textblabla textbla=textblabla url="http://www.link2.com">textblabla textblabla=textblabla textblabla
url="http://www.link3.com"> textblabla textblablabla=bla
```

Desired output:

```
www.link1.com
www.link2.com
www.link3.com
```

Comment: A quick-and-dirty method with GNU grep: `grep -o '"[^"]*"' body.txt | grep -o 'www.*\.com'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`

```
$ grep -o 'www\.[^.]*\.com' input_file
www.link1.com
www.link2.com
www.link3.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

```
myStr='text more-text url="http://www.link1.com">textblabla textbla=textblabla url="http://www.link2.com">textblabla textblabla=textblabla textblabla url="http://www.link3.com"> textblabla textblablabla=bla';

for aString in ${myStr[@]}; do
    if [[ ${aString} =~ www.*?com ]]; then
      echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
    fi
done
```